# Getting wrong dates printed while calling a column for echo command

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to show only the year from a date field for my loop, but when I am trying to call it, it shows me the wrong year. It shows 1970 for all the results.

I'm new to wordpress and php and don't know how to exactly show my results. Is my query for `$mydate` incorrect or is it a coding error when being echoed?

```
<table class="teachpress_publication_list">

      <?php

        global $wpdb;

    // QUERY HERE TO COUNT TOTAL RECORDS FOR PAGINATION 
    $total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub LIMIT 0,650) AS a");
    $post_per_page = 10;
    $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
    $offset = ( $page * $post_per_page ) - $post_per_page;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $post_per_page OFFSET $offset");
    $mydate = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT date FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>

          <tr class="tp_publication">

                  <td class="tp_pub_info"> <p class="tp_pub_author"> <?php echo $print->editor; ?><br/>
                  <span class="tp_pub_title"> <?php echo $print->title; ?></span><br/><?php echo $print->journal; ?>&nbsp;<span class="dd">Year Published:<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($mydate)); ?></span> </p>

          </tr>

            <?php }
          ?>
</table>
```

I expect the output to show the correct year in the date column of MySql db instead of always 1970.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess that `$mydate` is not actually a date, but something like an array.

Comment: thanks for the quick response but how to get my results mentioned above am completely new bee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out just used print function along with date() function

```
<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($print->date)); ?>
```

Now am able to display only year from my db column.

Thanks a lot all for the support!

Hariharan

Answer (score 0):

The doc of get_resulst function

> wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT )
>
> Retrieve an entire SQL result set from the database (i.e., many rows)

So $mydate is an object in this case. 1970 is the default year when the argument you pass to that function is wrong.

I think something like that shoul will work:

```
$mydate = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT date FROM wpfs_teachpress_pub LIMIT 1", ARRAY_N);
```

And then:

```
<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($mydate[0])); ?>
```

Or get $mydate inside the loop if each result can have a different date.

Regards.

Comment: I'm not a worpdress expert... Maybe you can use get_var instead https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/

Comment: Hi thanks pabgaran but after modifying the code like you mentioned still its returning 1970 as the result and i have a column called 'date' and it has several dates for each row and i want each row to be matched with correct data when echoed in my loop.